# VMware The virtual machine couldnot start

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I virtualized VMware for MAC OS X but when I start my VM it says the following

> The virtual machine could not start. Make sure VMware Workstation is installed correctly and you have rights to run the software and to access all directories it uses, including directories in which the software is installed, directories containing the virtual disk and configuration files, and directories for temporary files.

Any help?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the host OS and what is the VM os?

Comment: HOST OS win7 64bit, VMware workstaion 8 trying to run MAC OS X 10.7 on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved or altered the .vmwarevm files? these are the actual HDD files that store your virtual machine. They can be readded by opening them again with VMware.

Comment: No I have not altered them, I deleted the whole VM and and made it again, but of no use!

Comment: Yes I did, I guess the problem was with the unlocker I was using, I used the same for VMware 7.1 it workd fine now!